# What does \nop mean and how to use it

Tags: macros

I wonder what does the `\nop` mean, and how does it work? I Googled it but couldn't find a good answer, for example, I found something like:

```
\newcommand{\nop}[1]{}
```

in my `.tex` file, so what does it mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your example, `\nop` is defined to take a single argument and do nothing with it. As such, `\nop` literally translates to "perform **n**o **op**eration", or "gobble your argument". In fact, there exists a similar core macro `\@gobble` (and friends) which does exactly the same (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\long\def \@gobble #1{}
\long\def \@gobbletwo #1#2{}
\long\def \@gobblefour #1#2#3#4{}
```

The first gobbles a single argument, making `\@gobble{<anything>}` expand to *nothing*. The second gobbles two arguments, making `\@gobbletwo{<anything>}{<anything>}` expand to *nothing*, and so on.

What's the use case here? Well, perhaps you define a macro that writes something in the margin, like a "to do" note:

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{\marginpar{Do #1}}
```

Now, later in your production, you decide that this operation is no longer valid/useful. So, you can make `\mymacro` act like `\nop` and do nothing, which allows you to leave your code as-is:

```
\let\mymacro\nop
```

or, at definition in your preamble, change it to a no-op:

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{}
```

Comment: another thing that confused me is that any paragraph that is enclosed in this \nop{} command using the macro in the example, is disappeared, so i wonder why.

Comment: @daiyue -- making anything presented as an argument to `\nop` disappear is exactly its purpose.

Comment: Something like `\nop` is also frequently used in conjunction with `BibTeX` to fix the sorting order.

Comment: The nop definition in the question, produces an extra space.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: you can add `\ignorespaces` or `\unskip` or use a trailing `%`.

Comment: Thanks: `\newcommand{\nop}[1]{\ignorespaces}` seems to work. (comment added so others and I know where to add command).